# How to enforce a max limit no. of rows per day per date in SQL?

Tags: sql, date, amazon-athena

Given a data that looks as follows where the date is in string format `YYYYMMDD`:

| item | vietnamese | cost | unique_id | sales_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fruits | trai cay | 10 | abc123 | 20211001 |
| fruits | trai cay | 8 | foo99 | 20211001 |
| fruits | trai cay | 9 | foo99 | 20211001 |
| vege | rau | 3 | rr1239 | 20211001 |
| vege | rau | 3 | rr1239 | 20211001 |
| fruits | trai cay | 12 | abc123 | 20211002 |
| fruits | trai cay | 14 | abc123 | 20211002 |
| fruits | trai cay | 8 | abc123 | 20211002 |
| fruits | trai cay | 5 | foo99 | 20211002 |
| vege | rau | 8 | rr1239 | 20211002 |
| vege | rau | 1 | rr1239 | 20211002 |
| vege | rau | 12 | ud9213 | 20211002 |
| vege | rau | 19 | r11759 | 20211002 |
| fruits | trai cay | 6 | foo99 | 20211003 |
| fruits | trai cay | 2 | abc123 | 20211003 |
| fruits | trai cay | 12 | abc123 | 20211003 |
| vege | rau | 1 | ud97863 | 20211003 |
| vege | rau | 9 | r112359 | 20211003 |
| fruits | trai cay | 6 | foo99 | 20211004 |
| fruits | trai cay | 2 | abc123 | 20211004 |
| fruits | trai cay | 12 | abc123 | 20211004 |
| vege | rau | 9 | r112359 | 20211004 |

The goal is sample all the rows within a certain time frame, e.g. 2020-10-02 to 2020-10-03 and to extract a maximum of 3 rows per day, e.g. with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE sales_date BETWEEN '20211002' AND '20211003'
ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 6
```

the expected output for the table above is:

| item | vietnamese | cost | unique_id | sales_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fruits | trai cay | 8 | abc123 | 20211002 |
| fruits | trai cay | 5 | foo99 | 20211002 |
| vege | rau | 8 | rr1239 | 20211002 |
| fruits | trai cay | 12 | abc123 | 20211003 |
| vege | rau | 1 | ud97863 | 20211003 |
| vege | rau | 9 | r112359 | 20211003 |

But there is a possibility that all 6 rows expected comes from a single day:

| item | vietnamese | cost | unique_id | sales_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fruits | trai cay | 12 | abc123 | 20211002 |
| fruits | trai cay | 14 | abc123 | 20211002 |
| fruits | trai cay | 8 | abc123 | 20211002 |
| fruits | trai cay | 5 | foo99 | 20211002 |
| vege | rau | 8 | rr1239 | 20211002 |
| vege | rau | 1 | rr1239 | 20211002 |

So to ensure that I have max 3 rows a day, I'm running multiple queries per day, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE sales_date='20211002'
ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 3
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE sales_date='20211003'
ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 3
```

**Is there a way to ensure N no. of max limit rows per day in a single query?**

**Otherwise is there a way to combine those one query per day into a "super-query"?** If we're talking about a full year, it'll 365 queries, one per day.

Comment: Combine them with `select ... UNION ALL select ...`

Comment: Note that with your example, 6 rows covering 2 days, there must be exactly 3 rows per day.

Comment: LIMIT N or TOP N always delivers the first N rows delivered in a random fashion. This is standard behaviour. The trick is to use the ROW_NUMBER function to enumerate your result set first by date, then select only those rows where the number is up to N. Bit of overkill for sampling. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_ROW_NUMBER.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 6 rows over 2 days means exactly 3 rows per day, let's expand it to a week.

In a subquery use [`row_number`](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-row_number/) to assign a number to each row for each date. Then only select those with a row number of 3 or less.

```
select *
from (
  select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by sales_date order by rand()) as row
  from mytable
  where sales_date between '20211002' and '20211009'
)
where row <= 3
order by rand()
limit 6
```

Comment: Thanks! That's an elegant solution. A small follow up, if I need to aggregate some the item field with `group by`, would `row_number() over (partition by max(sales_date) order by rand()) as row` still work as expected?

Comment: @alvas I'm not sure. Window functions are executed after group by, so it should work. Try it.